# [RequestHeaders], [CalendarContentScript], [SXT] and other annoying console messages are appearing in Chrome Console

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools, webpack-2, google-chrome-console

My webapp is working fine, but this morning I suddenly started seeing 5 new console info messages appearing when I browse to the app in Chrome.

The console messages include;

- [RequestHeaders] os=Windows; osVer=10.0; proc=Win32; lcid=en-us; deviceType=0; country=n/a; clientName=sxt; clientVer=913/10.2.0.9800/sxt
- [CalendarContentScript]::initialize...
- contentscript.ts:22 [SXT]::Content script init
- contentscript.ts:29 [SXT]::Content script response Object {ecs: Object}
- backpackModule.ts?c78a:45 [BackpackModule]::disbled - no onClientInit

My app uses webpack2. These console messages didn't appear before now and they all seem to be informational.

Any ideas why this is happening and what I should try and get rid of them...?

The first console message for Angular is normal, so ignore that one. It's the others that are annoying me...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OMG after ages trying to figure this out, it turns out the new console messages were due to the Skype Chrome Extension that installed itself when I updated skype... I've disabled the extension and the messages are gone.

Hope this saves someones life one day.